# App crashes when ItemClicked in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

In my app, I have a ListView that shows the values I set (contact list for example). When I click in any of the values, my app crashes. But in the code there is no `OnItemClickListener` to even give me a reason for the problem.

LogCat:

```
10-08 20:14:07.453: E/AndroidRuntime(261): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-08 20:14:07.453: E/AndroidRuntime(261): java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed
10-08 20:14:07.453: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.database.CursorWindow.getString_native(Native Method)
10-08 20:14:07.453: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:329)
10-08 20:14:07.453: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:49)
10-08 20:14:07.453: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at com.example.mensagem.Mensagenssalvas$1.onItemClick(Mensagenssalvas.java:59)
10-08 20:14:07.453: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
10-08 20:14:07.453: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)
10-08 20:14:07.453: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
10-08 20:14:07.453: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-08 20:14:07.453: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-08 20:14:07.453: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-08 20:14:07.453: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-08 20:14:07.453: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-08 20:14:07.453: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-08 20:14:07.453: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-08 20:14:07.453: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-08 20:14:07.453: E/AndroidRuntime(261):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My .java code: (which does not contain a `OnItemClickListener`)

```
public class Mensagenssalvas extends Activity {

    public SQLiteDatabase db;

    ArrayList<String> list = null;
    Cursor c;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mensagenssalvas);

    db = openOrCreateDatabase("banco.db", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);

    Mensagens();
}

private void Mensagens() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ListView user = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMensagens);
    String[] campos = new String[] {"mensagenssalvas", "mensagemsalva"};

    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    c = db.query( "mensagens", campos, null, null, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    if(c.getCount() > 0) {
        while(true) {
           list.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("mensagenssalvas")).toString());
            if(!c.moveToNext()) break;
        }
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

    user.setAdapter(adapter);


   }
 }
```

Why is it showing errors if I don't even have an `OnItemClickListener` in my code?

Comment: Did you create _id field in table in your database file ?

Comment: Interesting. The error originates from line 59 in `Mensagenssalvas.java`, which line is this?

Comment: @ManishAndroid Yes indeed but thats not related to the problem i guess.

Comment: @Sam I check with some people at my work and they said it could be a Emulator problem(which sometimes it gets crazy) so I setted up a dialog Message when click and worked fine, then i removed it and no error at ALL. So the emulator was probably buggy. and the line 59 is: `}` (the last bracket) '-' curious.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to extend `ListActivity` instead of `Activity`? Also have a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Comment: @ccpizza No, i guess, it works fine in many of my Apps which the .XML file is just a ListView.

Comment: Curious is a mild statement... this error makes no sense in this context. :) Maybe you had an OnItemClickListener in a previous version and the emulator wasn't running the most recent code? But it sounds like you have a working app again, so I'm glad you're able to move forwards. PS I recommend using a SimpleCursorAdapter when working with Cursors. They are more powerful.

Comment: @MrG.Knowledge You are using a 'pre-coocked' built-in view `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` which I suspect might be causing the problem. Either have a look at its source in the AOSP tree to see what it includes, i.e. it might contain a predefined onItemClick handler, or just write your own custom `list_item`. Maybe that built-in view expects to be used inside a `ListActivity` only.

Comment: @Sam Well yes, thank you, but about the SimpleCursorAdapter I don't know how to use(I can learn of course) and I do work in a Office which requires the simplest way of the Apps we built, but thanks for recommendation.

Comment: @ccpizza The error was in the Emulator which was a little buggy, thanks for keeping it up and trying to help. As mentioned above to Sam, we keep it simple for easy use. Thanks.